# How how to select more than one model with workflow_set (tidymodels) based on different metrics

Tags: r, classification, workflow, glmnet, tidymodels

I ran the the following models properly and I need to choose the best two (for one or more metrics). The difference between models are the recipes objects that take differents steps for unbalanced data (without, smote, rose, upsample, step_adasyn). I am interesting in select more than one, the best two and also select by unbalanced function.

````
                      yardstick::sensitivity, yardstick::specificity, 
                      yardstick::precision, yardstick::recall )
folds <- vfold_cv(data_train, v = 3, strata = class)

rec_obj_all <- data_train %>% 
  recipe(class ~ .) %>%
  step_naomit(everything(), skip = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) 

rec_obj_all_s <- data_train %>% 
  recipe(class ~ .) %>%
  step_naomit(everything(), skip = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_smote(class)

rec_obj_all_r <- data_train %>% 
  recipe(class ~ .) %>%
  step_naomit(everything(), skip = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())  %>%
  step_rose(class)

rec_obj_all_up <- data_train %>% 
  recipe(clas ~ .) %>%
  step_naomit(everything(), skip = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_upsample(class)

rec_obj_all_ad <- data_train %>% 
  recipe(class ~ .) %>%
  step_naomit(everything(), skip = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_adasyn(class)

lasso_mod1 <- logistic_reg(penalty = tune(),
                          mixture = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

tictoc::tic()

all_cores <- parallel::detectCores(logical = FALSE)
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(all_cores-4)
plan(cluster, workers = cl)

balances <- 
  workflow_set(
    preproc = list(unba = rec_obj_all, b_sm = rec_obj_all_s, b_ro = rec_obj_all_r,
                   b_up = rec_obj_all_up, b_ad = rec_obj_all_ad), 
    models = list(lasso_mod1),
    cross = TRUE
  )

grid_ctrl <-
  control_grid(
    save_pred = TRUE,
    parallel_over = "everything",
    save_workflow = FALSE
  )

grid_results <-
  balances %>%
  workflow_map(
    seed = 1503,
    resamples = folds,
    grid = 25,
    metrics = metrics_lasso,
    control = grid_ctrl,
    verbose = TRUE)
    

parallel::stopCluster( cl )

tictoc::toc()```

I don´t understand what is the correspond function to select the best two or more models with the package workflowsets.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [convenience functions in workflowsets](https://workflowsets.tidymodels.org/articles/articles/tuning-and-comparing-models.html) to rank results and extract the best results, but if you have more specific use cases like you describe here (best two, or best based on more complex filtering) then go ahead and use [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) + [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) verbs to handle your results in `grid_results`. You can `unnest()` and/or use the results of [`rank_results()`](https://workflowsets.tidymodels.org/reference/rank_results.html) to get out what you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks Julia Silge, I'm going to make the suggestion you have given me, and see how it turns out.